# Receiving error when attempting to verify a virtual machine order

Tags: go, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I run the below code I get the error `SoftLayer_Exception_InvalidValue: Invalid value provided for 'blockDevices.device'. A device number must be provided for all block devices. (HTTP 200)`

What is wrong with the way I initialize the block devices?

I see the fields, `Id` and `Uuid` for type `Virtual_Disk_Image`, but no number. From the descriptions it sounds like these values are set post-creation.
https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/blob/master/datatypes/virtual.go#L91

```
func verifyOrderTest(c Creds) (string, error) {
    sess := session.New(*c.user, *c.key)
    service := services.GetVirtualGuestService(sess)
    guestTpl := getGuestTplTest()
    guest, err := service.GenerateOrderTemplate(&guestTpl)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    productOrderInstance := services.GetProductOrderService(sess)
    _, err = productOrderInstance.VerifyOrder(guest)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return "success", nil
}

func getGuestTplTest() (datatypes.Virtual_Guest) {
    blockDevices := make([]datatypes.Virtual_Guest_Block_Device, 2)
    blockDevices[0] = datatypes.Virtual_Guest_Block_Device{
        DiskImage: &datatypes.Virtual_Disk_Image{
            Capacity: sl.Int(100),
            LocalDiskFlag: sl.Bool(true),
        },
    }
    blockDevices[1] = datatypes.Virtual_Guest_Block_Device{
        DiskImage: &datatypes.Virtual_Disk_Image{
            Capacity: sl.Int(100),
            LocalDiskFlag: sl.Bool(true),
        },
    }

    guestTpl := datatypes.Virtual_Guest{
        BandwidthAllocation: sl.Float(10),
        BlockDevices: blockDevices,
        Datacenter: &datatypes.Location{Name: sl.String("dal13")},
        DedicatedAccountHostOnlyFlag: sl.Bool(true),
        Domain: sl.String("website.com"),
        Hostname: sl.String("hostname"),
        OperatingSystemReferenceCode: sl.String("UBUNTU_16_64"),
        LocalDiskFlag: sl.Bool(true),
        MaxMemory: sl.Int(32768),
        StartCpus: sl.Int(16),
    }
    return guestTpl
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the attribute ¨Device¨ for each  Virtual_Guest_Block_Device object and the ¨ LocalDiskFlag ¨ attribute must be added once and not for each Virtual_Guest_Block_Device.

The same that this example:

```
blockDevices := make([]datatypes.Virtual_Guest_Block_Device, 2)
       blockDevices[0] = datatypes.Virtual_Guest_Block_Device{
              Device: sl.String("0"),
              DiskImage: &datatypes.Virtual_Disk_Image{
                     Capacity: sl.Int(100),
              },
       }
       blockDevices[1] = datatypes.Virtual_Guest_Block_Device{
              Device: sl.String("2"),
              DiskImage: &datatypes.Virtual_Disk_Image{
                     Capacity: sl.Int(100),
              },
       }
```

After that you have to add the symbol ¨&¨ to the parameter  ¨ guest ¨ in the method
VerifyOrder without this the code will not run.

```
result, err := productOrderInstance.VerifyOrder(&guest)
```